# jQuery missing after I moved my site from one host to another

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, hosting, web-hosting

I moved my site `bugdevstudios.com` from one hosting to another and It started giving me following errors that jQuery is missing. The site was working perfectly on first hosting. Please advice me what to do.

[image]

Comment: Your basic jquery file is missing. Include it from CDN hosting or from your server hosting directory

Comment: Why was it working on my first hosting then?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't move the site properly. Double check to make sure you moved everything to the correct paths and replicated the same configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just had a quick look at the site in my browser and I couldn't see jQuery included in your source code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Stick this tag in your `<head></head>` section and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function